# New Microsoft Edge install removed my Visual Studio code. Anyone else have this issue?

Tags: windows

My windows update installed the new Microsoft Edge browser this morning. But removed my Visual Studio Code Icon from windows taskbar. When I manually look for VS code and try to open any project, it said it can't find the item. So I ended up reinstalling it and it is back now.

I am wondering if anyone else have seen this issue or it is just me.

Thank you.